# Pandas: str.extract() giving unexpected NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data set which has a column that looks like this

```
Badge Number
1
3
23 / gold
22 / silver
483
```

I need only the numbers. Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('badges.xlsx')
df['Badge Number'] = df['Badge Number'].str.extract('(\d+)')
print(df)
```

I was expecting an output like:

```
Badge Number
1
3
23
22
483
```

but I got

```
Badge Number
Nan
Nan
23
22
Nan
```

Just to test, I dumped the dataframe to a .csv and read it back with pd.read_csv(). That gave me just the numbers, as I need (*though of course that's not a solution*)

I also tried

```
df['Badge Number'] = np.where(df['Badge Number'].str.isnumeric(), df['Badge Number'], df['Badge Number'].str.extract('(\d+)'))
```

but that just gave me all 1s. I know I am trying things I don't even remotely understand, but am hoping there's a straightforward solution.

Comment: try `df['Badge Number'] = df['Badge Number'].astype("string").str.extract('(\d+)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is while reading the XLS it self, specify your column to string.

use `dtype={'Badge Number': str}`

```
df = pd.read_excel('badges.xlsx',dtype={'Badge Number': str})
df['Badge Number'] = df['Badge Number'].str.extract('(\\d+)')
```

Comment: @Dr Phil  Though I do not know the exact metrics, astype(str) may be one more additional operation on dataframe. My guess when importing XLS, the data will be type casted to some default type, instead we are saying make it string type.

Answer (score 3):

That's almost certainly because the numbers are actually integers, not strings. Try filling the missing values by the original numbers.

```py
df['Badge Number'] = df['Badge Number'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0].fillna(df['Badge Number'])#.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `expand` to False

```
df['Badge Number'] = df['Badge Number'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)
df
Out[412]: 
  Badge Number
0            1
1            3
2           23
3           22
4          483
```

Comment: Once I used .astype(str), it worked. expand=False wasn't needed for my use case.